# how can i activate dos2unix on files that loacated in google cloud using gsutil?

Tags: linux, file, cloud, gsutil, dos2unix

I have files in my GCP bucket and I am trying to activate dos2unix on those files.
I couldn't find (after 1 hour of searching) any commands that allow me that.
I try that:
gsutil dos2unix gs://my-google-bucket/short_1000rows.csv

but it didn't work.
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

GCS objects are immutable (their bytes, not their metadata); you can't change any part of the object without completely replacing it.  Aside from operations like rewrite or compose, you have to re-upload an object if you want to change its contents.  So, you'll basically have download all the objects, run `dos2unix` on them, and then re-upload them to your bucket.  You may want to make use of `gsutil rsync` to do steps 1 and 3.