# GCP : Bigquery to export data with CRLF as line termination

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, unix, google-bigquery, airflow

I tried to export the data to CSV in BigQuery, by default it generate the export file with **LF** as line termination,

```
export data options(uri = 'gs://<bucket>/<file_name>.txt', format = 'CSV',overwrite = true, header = false, field_delimiter = '~') as select * from <table> order by <col>
```

Is it possible to export the data with **CRLF** as line termination by providing some parameters in export data in BigQuery? Kindly share your thoughts

EDIT : requirement is to achieve the expected results through AIRFLOW, if any direct way to achieve this by adding any BQ EXPORT param, that would be great. if not, by using PYTHON Operator or BASH operator in Airflow, would be helpful

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Python so it's not clear why you included the `python` tag. Similarly, you included the `unix` tag which implies you are running your program on a Unix like OS where **LF**, not **CRLF**, is the expected line ending. Your question is incoherent and obviously missing some important context. For example, are you running your program on a Unix OS but need the resulting file to use the Windows convention for text files? If so, why can't you just post-process the file using a command like `unix2dos` to change the line endings?

Comment: Let me include few more details here.. I am looking for solution in BQ EXPORT command, is there any parameter that can help to achieve CRLF by overwriting the default line termination LF.. If there is no straight forward BQ parameter to achieve this.. I need to look for PYTHON operator or BASH operator in Airflow to process the file, once BQ export is completed.. Hope this clarifies your concerns..

Comment: Reason for CRLF is due to downstream consumption constraints

Comment: Please don't put important details in comments. Edit your original question to include those details. You still haven't answered most of my questions. What does Python have to do with this problem? What does Unix have to do with this problem? You have apparently shown us a Google BigQuery "export" command. But you don't tell us on what OS you are executing that code. Are you using the BQ command-line tool to execute the statement in your question? You should update your question to provide more context about how, and where, you are executing that statement.

Comment: I just included the information in the Edit.. Python and Unix was included as the only other way to achieve is through Airflow, Python/Bash Operator.. please let me know, if any further query !!

Comment: I downvoted your question because, despite my prompting, you still have not modified your question to make it clear what you are doing and what the problem is. You really need to make fewer assumptions about what people reading your question know about your situation. I understand that English is not your native language. Nonetheless, your question still lacks important details and context.

Comment: You also stated that you need to look for a Python or Bash way to produce CSV that uses **CRLF** line endings. I already told you how to do so. Use the `unix2dos` program. If that can't be installed on your system it is trivial to implement.

Comment: Your question is not "pretty clear". And why do you continue to write "PYTHON" and "BASH" in all uppercase? The alternative is to use a tool like the `unix2dos` command (which is trivial to implement) to convert the line endings of the text that is written by the Google BQ tool you are using. This is a trivial problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257030/discussion-between-mani-shankar-s-and-kurtis-rader).

Comment: Kindly have a look on this.. unix2dos wont work in this situation..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481428/how-can-i-activate-dos2unix-on-files-that-loacated-in-google-cloud-using-gsutil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways, we can mitigate this issue.. As I am looking for solution to handle it within Airflow

Solution one -> Python operator with Bash command

```
path='gs://file_path'
file_name='file_name'
retrieve_files_command = f'gsutil ls {path}{file_name}*.txt'
process = Popen(retrieve_files_command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)

#retrieve list of file that need to remove LF to CRLF
files, _ = process.communicate()

files = files.decode().split('\n')[:-1]

#loop through each file to remove LF with CRLF and create a new GCS file
for file in files:
    filename = file.split('/')[-1]
    dt=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    modify_files_command = f"gsutil cat {file} | sed -e 's/$/\\r/' | gsutil cp - gs://<destination_path>/file_name_{dt}.txt"
    
    try:
        subprocess.run(modify_files_command,shell=True, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print("{file} is not converted due to {e.stderr.decode('utf-8')}")
```

Solution two -> Python operator with  buffer size.. NOTE : Retrieve the list of files as like solution one

```
buf_size = 4096
for input_file in files:
    in_blob = bucket.blob(input_file)
    op_prefix_name='destination_path'
    dt=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")
    op_fn='file_name' + dt
    print("input is " + input_file)
    print("otp is " + op_prefix_name + op_fn)
    op_blob=bucket.blob(op_prefix_name + op_fn)
    with in_blob.open('r') as in_file, op_blob.open('wt') as opt_file:
      while True:
          chunk = in_file.read(buf_size)
          if not chunk:
              break
          opt_file.write(chunk.replace('\n','\r\n'))
```

In my case, solution two fits into my environment as the Astro may get strucked due to gsutil cat command, due to file size constraint, where as solution two is performant due to buffer size, tweak your buffer size as required